# How to set breadcrumbs for an article in Schema.org?

Tags: seo, schema.org, breadcrumbs

Using Schema.org, I would like search engines to read the breadcrumbs of my articles.

However, [`BreadcrumbList`](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList) is part of a [`WebPage`](https://schema.org/WebPage) but not a part of an [`Article`](https://schema.org/Article).

I can add a `WebPage` object to each article, but it seems a bit redundant and I'm not sure how search engines would treat it.

What is a right way of implementing both breadcrumb and article objects?
Real life examples would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Articles and web pages are different entities. For various reasons it makes sense not to blur the line between these entities. Articles have no breadcrumbs, web pages have. That’s why Schema.org defines the [`breadcrumb` property](http://schema.org/breadcrumb) only for `WebPage` (and sub-types).

The common and expected way is to provide a `WebPage` entity in addition to any entities you have on the page (like one or multiple `Article`).

The [`mainEntity` property](http://schema.org/mainEntity) (or the inverse [`mainEntityOfPage` property](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage)) is used to denote the primary entity that the web page describes.

So for a web page that contains a single article, you could have something like:

- `WebPage` `breadcrumb` `BreadcrumbList`
- `WebPage` `mainEntity` `Article`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [example](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs) on Google with schema.org

Comment: This example doesn't show how to contain breadcrumbs inside an article

Comment: You can add a new breadcrumb schema that is not part of a article.
If you use more than one breadcrumb Google says he use the first breadcrumb as main.
See: https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/news/2335753/matt-cutts-if-you-have-multiple-breadcrumbs-google-picks-the-first-one