# Multiple property in Schema.org JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am trying to make a JSON-LD like this:

```json
????: {
"@type": "Person",
"jobTitle": "CEO",
"givenName": "Name",
"familyName": "Name",
"email": "mailto:info@example.com"
}
```

What should I write where the "????" are, if the given information is both for employee, and founder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think JSON-LD doesn’t allow multiple properties for the same value.

But instead of repeating the data …

```json
"employee": {
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "John Doe"
},
"founder": {
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "John Doe"
}
```

… you could define the `Person` only one time, give it an URI, and reference this URI as value for `employee` and `founder`:

```json
"@type": "Person",
"@id": "/team/john-doe#i",
"name": "John Doe"
```

```json
"employee": {"@id": "/team/john-doe#i"},
"founder":  {"@id": "/team/john-doe#i"}
```

([details and a complete example with `@id`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776122/1591669))