# JSON-LD structured data: how to reference nodes inside other nodes?

Tags: reference, nodes, json-ld, structured-data

Let's say that I have an organization and an event inside my webpage. In the event node I want my "performer" property to be my organization. Is there a way to do it without rewriting everything?

I know this must be a stupid question, but I couldn't find anything on the internet. My best guess right now is "@id" but I didn't really understand its use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schema.org JSON-LD reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761970/schema-org-json-ld-reference)

Comment: Thanks, that partially answered my question. I get an error from google testing-tool though. I already have an *Event* declared somewhere in the page, and I would like to reference it in the _"event"_ property of the *Organization* (which in turn is referenced in the _"performer"_ property of the Event itself, any issue with this kind of "circular dependency"?). Problem is that google testing-tool still tell me that I'm missing name, location, ... if I just put the _"@id"_

Comment: Google (or at least Google’s testing tool) might not support such references ([it’s not documented](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41067598/1591669)).