# How to linking schema property data on different page

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I trying create schema markup for home and article pages using JSON-LD, home page using type blog and article page using blogposting type, i want add author property (in detail) on both pages at once.

UPDATE the question.
How to linking schema property data on different pages?

Comment: Do you look for a solution for your backend (e.g., for PHP or whatever you are using)? If yes, you need to give details about the system and include/describe what you have tried and where the problem is.

Comment: @unor I just want linking data from article page to home page, so i do not have write it twice.. What it work using `@id` only?, i just hesitate to use `@id`..

Comment: I don’t understand. You can of course provide a link as value for the `author` property, but you still have to add the `author` property to both pages. Or do you mean with "at once" that you don’t want to repeat the data about the author on both pages?

Comment: Ah! So i just write author property (image, sameAs etc) on one of the page and just use `@id` on another pages.

Comment: Yes. Does this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776122/1591669) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your help..